# How to find out why QML WebView page loading fails

Tags: qt, debugging, qt4, qml, qtwebkit

I try to open a local page (WebOS app) using QML WebView

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import QtWebKit 1.0
import com.nokia.meego 1.0

Page 
{
    id: mainPage
    Flickable
    {
        id: appFlickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true

        contentHeight: appView.height
        contentWidth: appView.width

        WebView
        {
            id: appView
            preferredHeight: parent.height
            preferredWidth: parent.width
            url: appUrl
            settings.javascriptCanOpenWindows: true
            settings.javascriptEnabled: true
            settings.autoLoadImages: true
            settings.javascriptCanAccessClipboard: true
            settings.developerExtrasEnabled: true
            onLoadFailed: console.log("load failed")
            onLoadFinished: console.log("load finished")
        }
    }
}
```

I load it in main.cpp this way:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QDeclarativeView view;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("appUrl", argv[1]);
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/main.qml"));
    view.showFullScreen();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I'm always getting a load fail. Is there any way I can find out the problem, enable some web console to show me what fails.

Thanks

Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `WebView::onLoadFailed` called on network errors (unreachable or invalid url etc.).

What you can try to do, is to listen to NetworkAccessManager's `finished` signal to check network reply for error.

```
connect (viewer.engine()->networkAccessManager(), SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
         logger, SLOT(onNetworkRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

Where `logger` is a QObject with `onNetworkRequestFinished` slot.

```
void Logger::onNetworkRequestFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        qDebug() << "network error:" << reply->errorString();
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

For details refer to `QNetworkReply` [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qnetworkreply.html).